# Eigenvalues of a 2 by 2 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that if the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix A is 0 and 1, then $A^2=A$.
I know that the if $A^2=A$, then the eigenvalues of A are 0 and 1. But I have no idea how to prove the this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can diagonalize the matrix.

$$A = PDP^{-1}$$

What would $D$ be? What happens if you then try $A^2$?

Comment: The diagonalization. Variance.

Answer (score 2):

Hint : since $A$ has *distinct* eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $x(x-1)$. By the Cayley-Hamilton theorem, $A(A-I)=A^2-A=0$.